# Can't Start MySQL with XAMPP, Err Code: 10013

Tags: mysql, xampp

I'm facing a weird trouble nowadays. I couldn't figure it out. I was using XAMPP without any problems until 2 days ago. Nothing installed or uninstalled, nothing changed. But suddently it gives me this error and doesn't works;

> Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.

In mysql_error.log:

```
2020-09-13 10:41:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-09-13 10:41:04 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-09-13 10:41:04 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-09-13 10:41:04 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10013: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
2020-09-13 10:41:04 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2020-09-13 10:41:04 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

- I checked if the port is in use. `It's not.`
- I tried to restart computer. `(Of course)`
- I tried to uninstall/reinstall XAMPP. `Nothing changed.`
- Checked firewall if it's blocking port. `None.`
- Disabled antivirus, firewall, Windows Defender. `Sigh -_-`

One last thing remained in my mind is: REINSTALLING WINDOWS. Please don't make me do this

Answer (score 5):

Old question, but I'm posting it in case anyone is in the same situation. I checked with nstat if the port was in use, but that wasn't the case. I knew I had docker installed in my windows machine, yet nstat didn't show anything using the port 3306. What I had to do was disable the Docker Desktop service from the boot section in the task manager. After rebooting I could start mysql in xampp withput issues.

Comment: How did you disable the docker desktop service?

Comment: Open Task Manager and go to the boot section, find Docker Desktop service and set to  disabled.